# Tech research disappearing from tree

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I noticed when I went into my tech tree, that there were several blank (unresearched) techs, most of which I know I already bought, including one of the first two you ever unlock. I'm finding myself having to purchase them again.

[image: tech tree image]

If this is a one-time bug, I'm fine with earning enough science to open them back up again, but I'm hoping there's a real fix. I have ships in orbit now with parts that are no longer available to me.

Some history -- have never enabled cheats of any kind, and I use no mods at all (and never have.)

I've already looked into "cheating" my way back to the tree I had before, but I'd rather fix the problem than band-aid the symptoms if at all possible. Anyone have any thoughts on what happened, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did the game update lately? If they changed the tre, some tech may have been reset

Comment: I've not seen an update for KSP for quite some time. I pay close attention to them, and it's been a while.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I would recommend to report it to [the bugtracker](http://bugs.kerbalspaceprogram.com/), but to be helpful for the developers there would need to be a way to reproduce the bug (I am a software developer myself and there is nothing worse than a bug report which only shows the error state but no indication whatsoever what could have lead to it).

Comment: Thanks, a bug has been filed (#5247) but I have no idea how reproducible the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the solution to this was to create a fresh game. My career game was old enough where the newer version of KSP caused an issue with the tech tree configuration. My game was created probably around the 0.2 to 0.3 time frame, so I just bit the bullet and created a fresh 1.04 career. The strange thing was that it just happened to pop up (not just after an update), but regardless, no other issues were found.